# Using scasb to count the appearances of a word in a sentence

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I've been working on some practice tasks for using masm and i figured out how to replace parts of a sentence with some character, in this case, spaces. But I can't for the life of me figure out how apply this same logic to counting the simply counting the occurrences of a word.

This is the example i figured out

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc     
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
                     
.stack 4096

.const
Space equ ' '
Punkts equ '.'

.data
buffer byte ' Test  test tes t  ', 0 
BufLen equ $ - buffer - 1


.code
start proc            
     push es
            push ds
            pop es
            xor bx, bx
            cld                   
      mov ecx, BufLen
            mov al, Space           
     lea edi, buffer
Next:
            repne scasb            
            jne No           
            mov es:[edi - 1], byte ptr Punkts
 
            inc bx
     cmp cx, 0
            jne Next
No:
            invoke StdOut, addr buffer
            pop es            
            push 0
            call ExitProcess 
start endp
        end start
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Cleanup

Use 32-bit registers and don't concern yourself with what's in the DS and ES segment registers in your Windows program (`kernel32.inc`, `kernel32.lib`, `call ExitProcess`).

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc     
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
                     
.stack 4096

.const
Space  equ ' '
Punkts equ '.'

.data
buffer byte ' Test  test tes t  ', 0 
BufLen equ $ - buffer - 1

.code
start proc
      mov  al, Space
      xor  ebx, ebx                   ; Count of replacements
      mov  ecx, BufLen
      mov  edi, addr buffer
Next: repne scasb
      jne  No
      mov  byte ptr [edi - 1], Punkts
      inc  ebx                        ; Increment the counter
      test ecx, ecx
      jnz  Next
No:   invoke StdOut, addr buffer
      push 0
      call ExitProcess
start endp
end start
```

### Counting the occurrences of a 1-character word

The same code as above but after removal of `mov  byte ptr [edi - 1], Punkts` that you obviously don't need.

### Counting the occurrences of a multi-character word

Like before, we look for the first character of the word, and if we find it we start an embedded loop ("inner loop") to look for the remaining characters. Have the inner loop not modify the ECX and EDI registers!
If this inner loop encounters a mismatch then you continue the outer loop just like before.
If this inner loop completes with nothing but matches then you increment the counter and you raise EDI by WordLen-1 and lower ECX by WordLen-1.

```
.data
TheWord byte 'Tom', 0
WordLen equ  $ - TheWord - 1
buffer  byte 'Tomorrow we meet Tom.', 0
BufLen  equ  $ - buffer - 1

...

      xor  ebx, ebx                   ; Count of occurences
      mov  ecx, BufLen
      mov  edi, addr buffer
OuterLoop:
      mov  al, TheWord                ; First character is 'T'
      repne scasb
      jne  No

InnerLoop:     ; Compare the 2nd char of the word with [edi] and so on

      ...

Match:
      inc  ebx                        ; Increment the counter
      add  edi, WordLen-1
      sub  ecx, WordLen-1
MisMatch:
      test ecx, ecx
      jnz  OuterLoop
No:
      invoke StdOut, addr buffer
      push 0
      call ExitProcess
```